# redirect doamin and sub domains to https://www

Tags: redirect, https, apache2, virtualhost, .htaccess

My website is written in CodeIgniter and hosted on Ubuntu 16.04
I have to redirect all domain and sub domains to https://www.

Ex: I want like this

```
http://com-download.live         --> https://www.com-download.live
http://youtube.com-download.live --> https://www.youtube.com-download.live
http://vimeo.com-download.live   --> https://www.vimeo.com-download.live
```

Note: Please suggest me the better way, where should I place redirect rules, In apache virtual host or in .htaccess ?

My Current code placed in virtual host is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)com-download\.live [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it's not working properly

http://www.com-download.live redirecting to `http://www.www.com-download.live`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion redirecting by htacces ll be easier, sample like:

```
 RewriteEngine On  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80  RewriteRule ^(.*)$
 https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

But take into the possibility of editing this in the future it would be better to set the redirection via the server, less emergency and easier to observe if you have many more domains

Example on console:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have also multiple sub domains as I have mentioned in question.

Comment: That why i recommend to made a  redirection via the server

Comment: please tell me, how to redirect via the server?

Comment: You have Apache2?

Comment: yeah, and hosted on Ubuntu 16.04
Please see I have edited question and given my current code

Comment: Just made a redirection from port 80 (http) to 443(https)

Comment: Try this one :

NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.example.com
   Redirect / https://secure.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
   ServerName secure.example.com
   DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
   SSLEngine On
# etc...
</VirtualHost>

After that u need to avoids caching issues so implement this:

 Redirect permanent / https://secure.example.com/

Comment: /etc/init.d/httpd restart

also restart is needed

Comment: if I do Redirect / secure.example.com it will work with domain but what about sub domain, ok, editing question with real domain and sub domain

Comment: Did you try ServerAlias *.example.com?

something like :
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName subdomain.example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.com

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1.example.com/$1 [R=302,L]
</VirtualHost>

Comment: not working your code it's not redirecting main domain, please se question once again I have edited

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Comment: Added your code it's working but not working when domain is already with https://youtube.com-download.live it should redirected to www.

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`